# How to compare sum of two int64 with INT64_MAX?

Tags: c++, integer

I know number greater than `INT64_MAX` will wrap around negative, So how to compare when sum  overflow, that is sum greater than `INT64_MAX`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int64_t a = INT64_MAX;
  int64_t b = 1;
  // cin >> a >> b;
  if (a + b <= INT64_MAX) {
    cout << "Yes" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "No" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I know int64 greater than INT64_MAX will wrap around negative* Not necessarily. `uint64_t` will wrap around to 0.  But the overflow behavior of signed integer types is undefined.

Comment: `I know int64 greater than INT64_MAX will wrap around negative,` - your knowing is wrong. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Subtract one operand from `INT64_MAX` and see if the result is greater than the second operand.

Comment: The usual way to predict whether `a + b` will overflow is to check whether `MAX - a` is greater than `b`, although you have to be careful if `a` or `b` might be negative.

Comment: See also [question 20.6b](http://c-faq.com/misc/intovf.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/), and especially [the footnote](http://c-faq.com/misc/sd26.html).

Comment: `if (a + b <= INT64_MAX)` -- Too late -- the horse has left the barn.  Once you did the addition, all bets are off.

Comment: You have 2 overflows to avoid, on positive side with `INT64_MAX` and on negative side with `INT64_MIN`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I had write a new version.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Pedantically, `a + b <= INT64_MAX` is not too late on a unicorn machine where `int` is wider than 64 bit.  Such machines I do not expect for another 30 years, if ever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First compare `b` to either `INT64_MIN - a` or `INT64_MAX - a` before the addition to prevent *undefined behavior* (UB) of *signed integer* overflow.

```
// True when sum overflows.
bool is_undefined_add64(int64_t a, int64_t b) {
  return (a < 0) ? (b < INT64_MIN - a) : (b > INT64_MAX - a);
}
```

Worst case: 2 compares.

For [div, mul, sub](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485)

Comment: why not return `bool` instead of `int`?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili No special reason other that in C it is one less `#include` from which code was originated.  Changed to `bool`.

Comment: in C you can always use `_Bool` without including anything. But then it's less portable to C++.

Answer (score 2):

Before compare, check `a + b` to see if it will overflow.

```cpp
int is_overflow(int64_t a, int64_t b) {
  if (((b > 0) && (a > (INT64_MAX - b))) ||
      ((b < 0) && (a < (INT64_MIN - b)))) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```